# How can I expose, together with my classes, the types imported from the glm Haxe lib?

Tags: python, haxe, haxelib

I am writing a class that I will translate to both Python and C#.
My code uses the nice "glm" library. Glm provides useful datatypes, e.g: `Vec3`.

Can I make `Vec3` visible to the Python and C# users of my class?
In other words, can I expose public methods using `Vec3` datatypes?

Here is a sample Haxe code with a class whose public function uses the `Vec3` type:

```haxe
// Test execution:
// haxe -main TestGLM1 -lib glm --interp
// Translate into Python:
// haxe -main TestGLM1 -python TestGLM1.py  -lib glm 
// python3 TestGLM1.py

import glm.Vec3;
import glm.Quat;
import glm.Mat4;


class TestGLM1 {

    public function new() {
    }

    static function main() {

        // My test of the method taking 3D datatypes as input and output
        var t: TestGLM1 = new TestGLM1() ;
        var v1: Vec3 = new Vec3(1,2,3) ;
        var v2: Vec3 = new Vec3(7,8,9) ;
        t.testVecIO(v1, v2);

        trace(v1, v2);
    }

    public function testVecIO(vec_in: Vec3 , vec_out: Vec3) {
        vec_out.x = vec_in.x + vec_out.x;
        vec_out.y = vec_in.y + vec_out.y;
        vec_out.z = vec_in.z + vec_out.z;
    }
}
```

I would like to write a Python test like this:

```
from TestGLM1 import TestGLM1
from TestGLM1 import glm_Vec3

print("Python Test...")

t = TestGLM1()

v1 = glm_Vec3(1,2,3)  # Vec3()
v2 = glm_Vec3(4,5,6)  # Vec3()
t.testVecIO(v1, v2)
print(v1, v2)

print("Python done.")
```

However, this test fails:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'glm_Vec3'

because the only class that I can see in `TestGLM1.py` is:

```
class glm_Vec3Base:
    _hx_class_name = "glm.Vec3Base"
    __slots__ = ("x", "y", "z")
    _hx_fields = ["x", "y", "z"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.z = None
        self.y = None
        self.x = None
```

which has both an unfriendly name and doesn't show a proper constructor.

Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the only class that I can see in TestGLM1.py is glm_Vec3Base

That's because `Vec3` is an [`abstract` type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html), and abstracts only exist at compile-time. The underlying type is indeed a class called `Vec3Base`, and if you check `Vec3.hx` you'll notice why it "doesn't have a proper constructor":

```haxe
class Vec3Base {
    function new() {}

    var x:Float;
    var y:Float;
    var z:Float;
}
```

You can also notice that all of `Vec3`'s methods are declared as `inline`. If they weren't (you can force this by compiling with `--no-inline`), your Python output would have an additional class named `glm__Vec3_Vec3_Impl_`. It has static methods for all of `Vec3`'s methods, since that's how abstracts work under the hood:

> A good question at this point is "What happens if a member function is not declared inline" because the code obviously has to go somewhere. Haxe creates a private class, known to be the implementation class, which has all the abstract member functions as static functions accepting an additional first argument `this` of the underlying type.

In summary, due to `Vec3` being implemented as an abstract, I don't think there's a convenient way to expose it to Python or C# users. Haxe-generated code in general isn't very suitable for being used like that. That's not to say there are no mechanisms to facilitate it at all. For instance, there's the [`@:expose`](https://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-expose.html) metadata for the JavaScript and Lua targets.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.
However, if Vec3 is abstract, I just wonder how it is possible to instantiate it with a ... = new Vec3(1,2,3).
As far as I know, abstract datatypes cannot be instantiated (at least in other OO languages like Java and C++).

Comment: Abstract types in Haxe actually have nothing to do with Java-style abstract classes. Check the article in the Haxe Manual I linked for a detailed explanation.